# Is there a way to skip preflight response not processed by Angular httpClient?

Tags: angular6, angular-httpclient

We are developing an Angular 6 app using httpClient and with withCredentials: true. When we are making a request to another port on the same server (from port 8010 to 8011), Firefox tries to make a preflight request. But it seems like our angular httpClient is trying to process this preflight response. We are using the below code. And we see that, the flow is entering the catchError block. Why is angular-httpclient prcessing preflight response? How do we handle this?

```
request(url: string, method: string, options?: any, xmlOptions?: any,
    isFullUrl:boolean = false): Observable<any> {
    const fullUrl = (isFullUrl) ? url : `${HttpService.BASE_URL}${url}`;
    return this.httpClient.request(method, fullUrl, options).pipe(
        map(resp => this.parseXML(resp, xmlOptions)),
        catchError(exception => this.processError(exception, xmlOptions))
    );
}

private processError(exception, xmlOptions) {
    this.notificationService.clear();
    this.notificationService.error(HttpService.UNEXPECTED_ERROR_OCCURRED);
    if(exception.error) {
        let errorObj = this.parseXML(exception.error, xmlOptions);
        return throwError(errorObj);
    }
    else {
        return throwError(exception);
    }
}
```

If we inspect the exception, the error message is `"Http failure response for (unknown url): 0 Unknown Error"`

Note: This is working fine in Chrome browser.